# How to Reference a Named Column in a Range of Rows in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, named-ranges

I want to loop through all the cells in in a named column of a set of rows selected by the user. However, I am not sure how to accomplish this.

[Named Column in Selection of Rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsMq4.png)

I have used the blow code to get the user selected range / rows, but I do not know how to go from there to get hold of the cells in the named column within this range.

```
Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Intersect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.intersect):

```
Sub Test()

Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, cl As Range
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Whichever sheet your working on
    Set rng1 = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)
    Set rng2 = Intersect(rng1, .Range("COLE")) 'Whichever name your named range is.
    For Each cl In rng2
        'Do something
    Next cl
End With    

End Sub
```

Note that upon canceling the inputbox, this will throw an error which you can solve with some error handling.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways to loop through every cell in the range `rng` and prove we visited each of them.

```
Dim r as Range
For Each r in rng
    r = "visited" 
Next r
```

And

```
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To rng.Cells.Count
    rng.Cells(i) = "visited"
Next i
```